# Data Movement Manager using combined cts queries

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I wanted to use a combined search query like the one documented [here](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/searches#id_20197) with a `QueryBatcher`. But i don't seem to get the results i expected. 
This is how my query looks:

```
<search xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
    <cts:element-word-query>
        <cts:element>id</cts:element>
        <cts:text>2</cts:text>
    </cts:element-word-query>
</search>
```

Using a simple `QueryManager`, this returns me a total count of, well lets say 50.

```
final QueryManager qMngr = client.newQueryManager();

final RawStructuredQueryDefinition query = qMngr.newRawStructuredQueryDefinition(new StringHandle().with("" +
       "<search xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search\" xmlns:cts=\"http://marklogic.com/cts\">" +
       "   <cts:element-word-query xmlns:cts=\"http://marklogic.com/cts\"><cts:element>id</cts:element><cts:text>2</cts:text></cts:element-word-query>" +
        "</search>").withFormat(Format.XML)
        );
// prints 50
System.out.println("Count by search: "+ qMngr.search(query, new SearchHandle()).getTotalResults());
```

Using a QueryBatcher with this query, i get returned every document in my database. QueryBatcher doesn't seem to use my query filter at all:

```
DataMovementManager dmm = client.newDataMovementManager();
QueryBatchListener listener = (a) -> System.out.println(a.getItems().length);
QueryBatcher queryBatcher = dmm
    .newQueryBatcher(query)
    .onUrisReady(listener);

dmm.startJob(queryBatcher);
queryBatcher.awaitCompletion();
// prints a few lines with 1000 and a few with some smaller number. 
// But WAY more than expected (50!) using the same query as before
```

So i digged into there `QueryBatcher` code an noticed [this call](http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20DataMovementManager%20dmm%20=%20client.newDataMovementManager();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20QueryBatchListener%20listener%20=%20(a)%20-%3E%20System.out.println(a.getItems().length);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20QueryBatcher%20queryBatcher%20=%20dmm%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.newQueryBatcher(query)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.onUrisReady(listener);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20dmm.startJob(queryBatcher);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20queryBatcher.awaitCompletion();).

```
UrisHandle results = queryMgr.uris(query, handle, start, null, forest.getForestName())
```

This is a call to a internal api in order to get all the uris for the onUrisReady listener. This seems to not use a combined cts query:

```
final Iterator<String> iterator = ((QueryManagerImpl) qMngr).uris(query, new UrisHandle(), 0, null, "my-forest").iterator();

int count = 0;
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
   iterator.next();
   count++;
}
// prints 1000
System.out.println("By uris: " + count);
```

Edit:
Using a combined query with a structured query actually works, but i sadly cannot use this:

```
final QueryManager qMngr = client.newQueryManager();
final StructuredQueryBuilder sqb = qMngr.newStructuredQueryBuilder();
final RawStructuredQueryDefinition query = qMngr.newRawStructuredQueryDefinition(new StringHandle().with("" +
        "<search xmlns=\"http://marklogic.com/appservices/search\">" +
            sqb.word(sqb.element("id"), "2").serialize() +
        "</search>").withFormat(Format.XML)
    );

DataMovementManager dmm = client.newDataMovementManager();
QueryBatchListener listener = (a) -> System.out.println(a.getItems().length);
QueryBatcher queryBatcher = dmm
    .newQueryBatcher(query)
    .onUrisReady(listener);

dmm.startJob(queryBatcher);
queryBatcher.awaitCompletion();
// returns 50 (in total, in multiple listener calls)
```

Is this a known bug or am i doing something wrong here ?

- Java client: 4.1.0
- MarkLogic: 9.0-6

Comment: Hi Michael, have you checked what sqb.word(sqb.element("id"), "2").serialize() evaluates to?  My thought is that this builder only will return search: query elements, and what you're getting might not be equivalent to the cts:query in the original XML.

Comment: I'm getting the same behavior - both StringQueryDefinition and StructuredQueryDefinition produce the correct results with a QueryBatcher, but neither RawStringQueryDefinition nor RawCombinedQueryDefinition do - both seem to ignore the query (I'm just using a simple word query). I recommend filing a bug at the marklogic-client-api github project.

Comment: Hi grechaw, dont pay to much attention to what the last code snippet produces. 
What this issue is about is the difference in output of QueryBatcher and a simple QueryManager search.
Using the same cts combined query, the QueryBatcher seems to completely ignore the query filters,  while the QueryManager does not.

Comment: @rjrudin Can this be fixed by the marklogic-client-api project ? I suspect the bug is in the /v1/internal/uris endpoint, see the queryMgr.uris code example.

Comment: I do think this is because the combined query is not supported (in the sense that it doesn't work) as you suspect.  I'd strongly suggest working around it if possible.  Unless you need search options and a search in the same call, I'd avoid the combined query payload.  I just think it would be a difficult gap to fill, as the handling of combined query on /v1/search is quite intricate.

Comment: Alright. I will nevertheless fill a github issue so the marklogic-client-api people know about this issue. Thanks alot, both of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix for this bug will appear in a future release once testing confirms the implementation.

Here's the issue in the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api/issues/965

Comment: Didn't see this issue. Thanks for posting.